# Extract mysql Database from CommandLine

Tags: apache, mysql, wampserver

I am using wamp server but something happend to it and now there is no way to make it come back to life.  I only have access to mysql command line, and i have some important databases there.

How can i export the database using commandline?
please help.

Comment: Or i can give you the IP Address and Port number, with username/pass, can somebody help me please. It is very important.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysqldump -h localhost --routines -u root -p dbname
```

Answer (score 1):

If the mysql server is not behaving normally, you might have some corrupted tables. It happens usually after an unscheduled restart. mysqldump won't be able to export corrupted tables.

If the mysql server is running, try connecting to it using phpmyadmin and use the built in tools to fix and check the tables

if the mysql server fails to start, check the log files and use the mysql command line tools to fix the issues

```
myisamchk --silent --force --fast --update-state /var/lib/mysql/dbname/*.MYI
```

(http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/how-to-repair-corrupted-mysql-tables-using-myisamchk/)

Answer (score 0):

First try to connect to Mysql server using the command line

**mysql -uUsername -p** and press enter.This will prompt for password.Enter the mysql server password.

Then use the [mysqlcheck](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) command to repair the server in case corruption has occured

COmmand for mysql-check : **mysqlcheck --repair --use-frm --all-databases**

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just copy the folders of the database to create a backup of MySQL databases.

Used to work.